# SQL (MySQL) select random set of records for each user

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I need to sample 100 records for each user (it's a column in the table).
Currently, I have this code:

```
    SELECT * FROM sn.sn_graph_reduced 
    where user = '643495915'
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 100
```

Obvously, I need to remove the where clause and add something that will sample 100 records for each user in the table.
Any help appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a rank query mysql does not have window functions for this type of results to get n records per group

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT g.*,
@r:= CASE WHEN @g = g.`user` THEN @r +1 ELSE 1 END rownum,
@g:= g.`user` user_group
 FROM sn.sn_graph_reduced g
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @g:=0,@r:=0) t2
ORDER BY `user` , RAND() 
) t
 WHERE rownum <= 100
```

Above query will give ranks to the record which belongs to same user group and in parent query you can limit records to 100 for each user